# Slider from different widgets

Tags: php, widgets, jquery, javascript

I need some advice.

I have added the possibility to pages to have categories with a plugin.
I have created a widget for a client that lets a user select a category from a page and select a subpage within that category.

So the widget on the homepage shows the title and a excerpt of the page content with a read more button to the page.

My design only has space for three widgets. I would like to be able to have more widgets to the page. So I thought of a slider for widgets....

See how I said 'thought'. I really have no javascript/jquery skills.
Can anyone push me in the right direction to be able to create a slider that is able to hold different widgets?

Hope I don't thought of something impossible....

M.

Answer (score 0):

Found a (half)solution.

[Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is very helpful. 
I integrated this in a template. The data now is static so that need to be changed.
I created a sidebar but now I need to loop through the widgets.
I think I'm trying to use [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130317/loop-through-widgets-in-sidebar)

Still any ideas/thoughts are more than welcome!