# Loop through Widgets in sidebar using widget array number?

Tags: widgets

[Loop through widgets in sidebar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130317/loop-through-widgets-in-sidebar)

This function from @birgire is almost perfect for me, but how do I call it using the sidebar array as the second parameter, rather than the widget ID. In his example, I would like to do something like this:

wpse_show_widget( 'lobby-sidebar', lobby-sidebar[0] );

In birgire's original post, he gets a Registered Widget called 'sidebar-1' and a registered widget with the ID 'calendar-2'.

Rather than trying to find the specific ID that WordPress assigns to a widget, I'd like the second parameter to be the array ID. That is far easier for me to find than the widget ID.

I modified birgire's function to use wp_get_sidebars_widgets();, but the codex says that's a private function not meant for theme development. I thought someone here might have a more elegant solution.

Comment: And what is `lobby-sidebar[0]`? Because it isn't correct PHP syntax, so it's a little bit hard to guess, what exactly are you trying to achieve...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż: sorry for the confusion. I added more explanation. I'll also add my modifications to the original post. I asked a new question rather than commenting on the original because my reputation score is very low.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this modification of the [original post by birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130317/loop-through-widgets-in-sidebar), but I don't know if it's "ok" to use wp_get_sidebars_widgets(); in this manner.

```
function wpse_show_widget_alt( $index, $id ) {
global $wp_registered_widgets, $wp_registered_sidebars;
    $did_one = FALSE;

    //This built-in func isn't meant for theme or plugin development. 
    //I don't know any other way to list widgets in an array sorted by sidebar.
$theWidgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
$widgetNumber = $theWidgets[$index][$id];

// Check if $id is a registered widget
if( ! isset( $wp_registered_widgets[$widgetNumber] ) 
    || ! isset( $wp_registered_widgets[$widgetNumber]['params'][0] ) ) 
{
    return FALSE;
}

// Check if $index is a registered sidebar
$sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
if ( empty( $wp_registered_sidebars[ $index ] ) 
    || empty( $sidebars_widgets[ $index ] ) 
    || ! is_array( $sidebars_widgets[ $index ] ) )
{
    return FALSE;
}

// Construct $params
$sidebar = $wp_registered_sidebars[$index];
$params = array_merge(
                //array( array_merge( $sidebar, array('widget_id' => $id, 'widget_name' => $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['name']) ) ),
                array( array_merge( $sidebar, array('widget_id' => $widgetNumber, 'widget_name' => $wp_registered_widgets[$widgetNumber]['name']) ) ),
                (array) $wp_registered_widgets[$widgetNumber]['params']
          );

// Substitute HTML id and class attributes into before_widget
$classname_ = '';
foreach ( (array) $wp_registered_widgets[$widgetNumber]['classname'] as $cn )
{
    if ( is_string($cn) )
        $classname_ .= '_' . $cn;
    elseif ( is_object($cn) )
        $classname_ .= '_' . get_class($cn);
}
$classname_ = ltrim($classname_, '_');
$params[0]['before_widget'] = sprintf($params[0]['before_widget'], $widgetNumber, $classname_);         
$params = apply_filters( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', $params );

// Run the callback
$callback = $wp_registered_widgets[$widgetNumber]['callback'];            
if ( is_callable( $callback ) )
{
     call_user_func_array( $callback, $params );
     $did_one = TRUE;
}
return $did_one;}
```